# Display order keeps getting reset and buggy Display settings

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, 17.10

When I use my laptop at work, I usually plug in two monitors and close the lid. Before Ubuntu 17.10, the system remembered the order that I chose the previous time that I connected them. After Ubuntu 17.10 however, I have to manually order them every time that I connect them.

Also, the "Displays" windows is very buggy: it sometimes does not want a screen to be dragged, sometimes snapping does not work all the time or at places that I do not want:

[image]

and the most annoying bug is that the window often does not show the "apply" button (i.e. it shows this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

).

Does anybody know where these problems come from and how I would be able to fix them?

---

An example of the order should be:

[image]

An example of how the displays are ordered most of the time:

[image]